Why Pyspark change numeric data from a json payload even when I read as string
When I'm reading some json payloads PySpark is changing the data even if I read it as a StringType and I want this as a String because I don't want to have each field as a column at this step. I just want to get this payload as String as it is in payload/source file
Locally I'm using Spark 3.3 in Jupiter Notebook with Glue 4 image
PySpark version: 3.3.0+amzn.1.dev0
Here my payload/source (test.txt):
{"payload":{"points":1220000000}}
{"payload":{"count":1550554545.0}}
{"payload":{"points":125888002540.0, "count":1550554545.0}}
{"payload":{"name": "Roger", "count":55154111.0}}

Here my code:
path = "/home/glue_user/workspace/jupyter_workspace/test/test.txt"
schema =  StructType([StructField('payload', StringType(), True)])
my_df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("inferSchema", "false").json(path)
my_df.show(truncate=False)

Here the result where PySpark is setting the float number in scientific notation, even when I read it as String.
+------------------------------------------------+
|payload                                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
|{"points":1220000000}                           |
|{"count":1.550554545E9}                         |
|{"points":1.2588800254E11,"count":1.550554545E9}|
|{"name":"Roger","count":5.5154111E7}            |
+------------------------------------------------+

Why I can't simply have my data as it is?
Why the final result is changed into my string field and receive this scientific notation?
i.e:

"count":1550554545.0
"count":1.550554545E9


I opened a spark ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-49616
It seems to me a bug, I don't want that the framework change the raw data when I read it as String.

Apparently the Spark 3.3, the one I'm using always set the scientific notation for the string that contains/is a json object and I couldn't solve that, I mean, I had to save it with the scientific notation and as we have another spark job I needed to read this payload with Decimal(20,0) to be able to read it, since IntegerType or LongType wasn't able to open the data with scientific notation.

I did a research little bit and asked my colleagues about it and I got to know, spark JSON reader automatically infers schema and you can't override it.
What you can do is read it as a text first and then try to covert values.
I got same issue while reading data from SQL DB and I used cast expression in query itself.
For your use this is working for me. I tried to use from_json, MapType, get_json_object all three but I think whenever we convert to json, spark will convert to scientific notation.
df = spark.read.text(path)
df = df.withColumn('value', regexp_replace('value', r'^\{"payload":', ''))
df = df.withColumn('value', regexp_replace('value', r'\}$', ''))


Hi @nikhil-tale
I tried this solution after you sent here but it also doesn't changed the fact that the number was previously changed by spark, I mean, when we replace the { and } to kind of "cheat"/tease the spark the spark had already changed the notation to the scientific and we will have the number with this scientific notation anyway.
Anyway thank you for the solution.

No, scientific notation was not there in when I tried this. You have not used json conversion anywhere right?

No JSON conversion was used.
If you df.show() you dataframe before and after this regexp_replace, are both with scientific notation or just the before one? Thank you @nikhil-tale
